# Entity framework 6: referring to UserProfile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to write an ASP MVC app with custom DBInitializer, but I'm getting error:

> Additional information: The member with identity
>   'MailMail.Models.MailDbContext.Video_UserProfile' does not exist in
>   the metadata collection.

I have Video class:

```
public class Video : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

And my DBInitializer:

```
 public class MailDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MailDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MailDbContext context)
        {
            UsersContext userContext = new UsersContext();

            if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }


            var mongol1 = new { Email="mail2@mail", UserName="Tom"};
            var mongol2 = new { Email = "mail@mail", UserName = "Karola" };
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(mongol1.UserName, "secret", mongol1);

            Task<UserProfile> user1Task = userContext.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.UserName == mongol1.UserName);
            user1Task.Wait();
            UserProfile user1 = user1Task.Result;

            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(mongol2.UserName, "123456", mongol2);
            Task<UserProfile> user2Task = userContext.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.UserName == mongol2.UserName);
            user2Task.Wait();
            UserProfile user2 = user1Task.Result; 



            Video video1 = new Video() {Name="Moje wideo", UserProfile=user1, Path = "~/App_Data/"+user1.UserId+"/Video1"};
            Video video2 = new Video() { Name = "Moje wideo", UserProfile = user1, Path = "~/App_Data/" + user1.UserId + "/Video2" };
            Video video3 = new Video() { Name = "Moje wideo", UserProfile = user2, Path = "~/App_Data/" + user2.UserId + "/Video3" };
            Video video4 = new Video() { Name = "Moje wideo", UserProfile = user2, Path = "~/App_Data/" + user2.UserId + "/Video4" };

            context.Videos.Add(video1);  //HERE ocures the error!
            context.Videos.Add(video2);
```

I think it might have something to do with different contexts. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had 2 different context, evn tho they both were pointing to the same Database.
My solution was: I've just copied

```
 public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

to my main DBContext class.
That solved the problem :-)